# Clojure using value from another required key in validation

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm relatively new to clojure and I'm looking for a way to use the value of one required key in the validation of another.  I can do it by creating another map with the two values and passing that, but I was hoping there was a simpler way.  Thanks

```
(s/def ::country string?)
(s/def ::postal-code   
  ;sudo-code
  ;(if (= ::country "Canda")
  ;(re-matches #"^[A-Z0-9]{5}$") 
  ;(re-matches #"^[0-9]{5}$"))
)

(s/def ::address
  (s/keys :req-un [
    ::country
    ::postal-code
    ::street
    ::state
  ]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with `multi-spec`:

```
(defmulti country :country)
(defmethod country "Canada" [_]
  (s/spec #(re-matches #"^[A-Z0-9]{5}$" (:postal-code %))))
(defmethod country :default [_]
  (s/spec #(re-matches #"^[0-9]{5}$" (:postal-code %))))

(s/def ::country string?)
(s/def ::postal-code string?)
(s/def ::address
  (s/merge
    (s/keys :req-un [::country ::postal-code])
    (s/multi-spec country :country)))

(s/explain ::address {:country "USA" :postal-code "A2345"})
;; val: {:country "USA", :postal-code "A2345"} fails spec: :sandbox.so/address at: ["USA"] predicate: (re-matches #"^[0-9]{5}$" (:postal-code %))
(s/explain ::address {:country "Canada" :postal-code "A2345"})
;; Success!
```

Another option is `and`-ing another predicate on your `keys` spec:

```
(s/def ::address
  (s/and
    (s/keys :req-un [::country ::postal-code])
    #(case (:country %)
       "Canada" (re-matches #"^[A-Z0-9]{5}$" (:postal-code %))
       (re-matches #"^[0-9]{5}$" (:postal-code %)))))
```

You might prefer the `multi-spec` approach because it's open for extension i.e. you can define more `defmethod`s for `country` later as opposed to keeping all the logic in the `and` predicate.